# redirecting a bad post from google with htaccess rewrite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, post

I have a problem with several search engines using bad post URLs.

Here is one of the URLs:

```
/?lang=frThe-Importance-of-Multilingual-Support-for-Consumer-Electronicsleading-translation-services-for-french-spanish-english-montreal-toronto-orlando-miami/real-estate-translation-service-provider-french-spanish-montreal-mississauga-quebec-toronto-orlando-miami-florida/
```

I have tried the following rewrite in my htaccess file. But it has not worked.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=frThe-Importance-of-Multilingual-Support-for-Consumer-Electronicsleading-translation-services-for-french-spanish-english-montreal-toronto-orlando-miami\/real-estate-translation-service-provider-french-spanish-montreal-mississauga-quebec-toronto-orlando-miami-florida\/
RewriteRule ^/ / [R=301]
```

What did I miss?

Comment: You're using a multilingual plugin? What is the correct post url?

Comment: `^/` should just be `^` or `^$`. Also need the `L` flag. `RewriteRule ^/ / [R=301,L]`

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/?(?:index\.php)?$ /? [R=301,L]`